# filtering DateField on the basis of substring in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

So I am using a `DateField` for displaying the date. Which when passed to a template using contexts, renders in the format `Nov. 4, 2018`

Now there are multiple entries of such dates in the database. And I want to filter on the basis of string of the date actually shown. i.e when I type in `Nov 4`, or `nov 4` or `NOV 4` in my search input field, it should show the matched result. More like a substring match.

Now the only problem is that i do not know how to convert `my_model.date` field in to `Nov. 4, 2018`.

`str(my_model.date)` returns 2016-11-04 and I do not want to parse this with `month_number-to-month_name` map

I think, any of the two solutions should work.

1) Django filters that allow me to do so.

2) converting `my_model.date` into `Nov. 4, 2018` string

Help please, been stuck on this forever now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you specifically mention rendering the date in a template, I'm not sure if the search operation you're referring to is a front-end, user-facing thing or a backend database query.

If you want to convert `my_model.date` to a prettier string before sending it to the template before display, you can process it in your view with `strptime` - this will give you the control that you're missing with the `str` wrapper: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior While there are template tags that can do this for you as well, doing it in your view is faster and better.

If this is a DB query, then remember that you can filter date objects by their attributes. For example, to get all instances created on November 11th, 2011:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    date__day = 11, 
    date__month = 11,
    date__year = 2018
)
```

Note the double underscores.

---

Responding to your comment, now that I better understand your goal:

Date fields do not store their more "verbose" date information in a queryable spot. If you want to be able to query for things like "Nov" instead of `11` then you'll need to add another attribute (or attributes) to your model to propagate that computed data into queryable containers.

If it were me, I would do this within `my_model`:

```
from datetime import date

...

rawDate = models.DateField(...) #your current date field
formatted_month = models.CharField(...)
formatted_day = models.IntegerField(...)
formatted_year = models.IntegerField(...)

...

def save(self):
    self.formatted_month = date.strftime(self.rawDate, '%b')
    self.formatted_day = date.strftime(self.rawDate, '%d')
    self.formatted_year = date.strftime(self.rawDate, '%Y')
    super().save()
```

Now you can perform your `NOV/nov/Nov` lookup like so:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    formatted_month__iexact = 'Nov'
)
```

This still requires you to split the month and day in your search term before hitting the database. If you wanted to squash these down a bit, you could instead store all of the formatted date info in a single field:

```
formatted_date = models.CharField(...)
...
def save(self):
    self.formatted_date = date.strftime(self.rawDate, '%b %d %Y')
```

Then if your query looks like "NOV 4", you could do:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(formatted_date__icontains='NOV 4')
```

Comment: No! this is not what is desired. 

" I'm not sure if the search operation you're referring to is a front-end, user-facing thing or a backend database query. " -> It is a back end work. Basically the user would type in the string which will be processed by the django backend server to send in the matched results.

I would like to search for `Nov 4` without having to create a name-number mapping.

Comment: "If you want to convert my_model.date to a prettier string before sending it to the template before display, you can process it in your view with `strptime` " -> Basically the browser is already rendering the sent in data (sent via context) in a pretty and desired format (`Nov. 4, 2018`). I just want to be able to search for this as if it were a string.

Comment: Oh, I understand now - my apologies. See my edit. Since Django's DateField does not store the stuff you want as attributes on the date itself (they are computed properties), you'll need to propagate some stuff into queryable containers.